# Printing Specific JSON array elements in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

A PHP script obtains data from a MySQL database and returns an array to javascript using JSON. I can get the results but I cannot get them to print them out individually.

The PHP code -

```
header('Content-type:application/json');

$link = @new mysqli(_HOST, _USER, _PASS, _DB); //constants 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    //failure
}
else
{

    //success

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE"; //the query should return two
                                               //columns from every selected row
    $mix = array();                            //array to return using JSON

    $result = $link->query($sqlQuery);

    if ($result->num_rows <= 0)
    {
        //no data
    }
    else
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())       //fetch loop
        {
            $mix["C1"][] = $row['COL1'];        
            $mix["C2"][] = $row['COL2'];        
        }
    }

    $result->free();

    // Close connection
    $link->close();
}
```

`print json_encode($mix); //this line wont show up in previous code formatting block for some reason.`

The Javascript / jQuery code -

```
$.ajax({ // ajax call
        url: 'serv.php', // server page
        data: 'fetch=1', //ignore any data
        dataType: 'json', // server return type
        success: function(data) // on success
        {
                for (var i in data) {
                    $('#someDiv').append( i + " = " + data[i] + '<br>');
                }
        }
    });
```

The output, as expected is like this -

```
C1 = 1,2
C2 = A,B
```

What I want to accomplish is to put these data (`1,2,A,B`) inside a form table element. And to do that I need to pick the every element of C1 or C2 individually.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself.

The following ajax call works-

```
$.ajax({ // ajax call
    url: 'serv.php', // server page
    data: 'fetch=1', //ignore any data
    dataType: 'json', // server return type
    success: function(data) // on success
    {
            for (var i in data["C1"]) {
                $('#someDiv').append( i + " = " + data["C1"][i] + '<br>');
            }
            for (var i in data["C2"]) {
                $('#someDiv').append( i + " = " + data["C2"][i] + '<br>');
            }
    }
});
```

Instead of accessing the data, I've tried to access the indices inside data. It was so simple.